# Как правильно присвоить значение объекту NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Есть код:

```
...
int num = [string intValue];
NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            result = @"ein";
            break;
        case 2:
            result = @"zwei";
            break;
...
```

Там, где result присваиваются значения, Xcode предупреждает:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning
> to 'NSMutableString *' from 'NSString*
> '

Как написать более правильный код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[result  setString:@"ein"];
```

Answer (score 0):

как то так

```
    int num = [string intValue];
NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            [result appendString:@“ein"];
            break;
….
```

Comment: вот тут http://idev.by/ios/829/ хорошая статья по работе со строками в Obj-C

Comment: и тут http://www.imaladec.com/story/nsmutablestring